# Khaaaaaaaan! (how to kill him)

Tags: magicka

How am I supposed to kill the orc chief Khan? He is faster than me, just grabs me and pummels me to death. I don't have enough time to really hurt him before he is able to grab me.

My fight with him looks something like this:

[image: screenshot with lots of blood flying around]

Any ideas on how to survive this boss fight?

Comment: "This is not a very good title.  Can you add some more unique words to it?"

Comment: @GnomeSlice Its not good, its greaaat!

Comment: I was going to edit the title, since the actual achievement has only 8 As in it - it'd keep the humor but also boost the actual ability of users to find it. But alas, you get "title must be at least 15 characters".

Comment: @Grace can we cheat with nbsp, or something like that?

Comment: No, and you can blame @balpha for this, you have my blessing to visit the Meta Tavern and spin the wheel on him. [He's the one who kinda reported non-displaying characters in title length count](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44011/zero-width-non-joiner-allows-unclickable-titles) so long ago.

Comment: @gra just random target to see if zero-width spaces still could pad comments

Comment: @NickT Gotcha. As you probably already know on account of your succesful test, yes, they still work in comments (and are now among the only methods available to do such, as the common exploits have been removed).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bubble immediately to buy yourself some time. Then you can use Time Warp and Haste to slow him down/speed yourself up enough to prepare a devastating attack and hope for a one shot.

Blizzard Balls (1Earth+4Ice) are particularly effective.

Comment: I used this method combined with strong stone walls (1 shield + 4 earth) to kill Khan.

Answer (score 3):

Use a charged-up water attack to knock him away from you, then hit him with a cold + lightning + arcane beam. It will freeze him solid and do massive damage.

Answer (score 2):

I tried like 50 times, finally I killed him with a Water area spell and then a lightning+arcane+cold beam.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to hold down Right <kbd>Shift</kbd> and tap <kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> while right-clicking as fast as possible. He'll be defeated before you know it.

Comment: What if you are using a azerty keyboard?
And by the way, how do you do that, tap a+s, right shift and rightclicking? I only got 2 hands you know.

Answer (score 1):

Try Using haste and use a spread of water to make him vulnerable to lightning then keep using normal lightning rays and haste. This is how I beat him in the 65th try I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I caught him in a few lines of volcanoes (`E`, `D`, `F`, `SHIFT+LMOUSE`, `SHIFT+LMOUSE`; repeat), he was dead before I realized I was in a boss fight.

Answer (score 0):

Cast Vortex on him, and he'll be defeated almost immediately.