# How do you unlock the "Khaaan!" achievement in Civ 5?

Tags: achievements, civilization-5

I played through the 100 turns of a Mongol scenario and didn't conquer the number of civs I was supposed to (5 for King in my case). But I didn't get the "Khaaan!" achievement either ("Run out of time to beat the Mongol scenario").

Does anyone know if it's bugged, or if there's a trick to unlocking it? I googled around a bit but wasn't able to find an answer. I'm not using any mods and I had an active Internet connection when I finished the game, can't think of anything else that would prevent it.

Right now Steam says 0.9% folks have unlocked it: http://steamcommunity.com/stats/CivV/achievements/

Comment: [Related](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15828/khaaaaaaaan-how-to-kill-him).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [civfanatics](http://forums.civfanatics.com/archive/index.php/t-435020.html) forum:

> Khaaan! requires an outright loss through both score and lack of
>   conquests.  If you want the achievement, easiest is to give all your
>   cities away to a remaining AI one turn before the end of the scenario,
>   then press end turn.

Comment: Awesome, that makes sense -- I did win via score in that game.  Thanks!